# How can i change the log level in spark-submit console output?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark (Pyspark) and when I run a spark-submit the spark log is very verbose. How can I change the log output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step -1 Configure log4j properties

We will use something called as Appender. As per log4j documentation, appenders are responsible for delivering LogEvents to their destination.

Append the following lines to your log4j configuration properties. You’ll find the file inside your spark installation directory – spark/conf/log4j.properties

```
# Define the root logger with Appender file 
  log4j.rootLogger=WARN, console 
# Define the file appender 
  log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
# Name of the log file 
  log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/logfile.out 
# Set immediate flush to true log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true 
# Set the threshold to DEBUG mode log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug 
# Set File append to true. log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true 
# Set the Default Date pattern log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd 
# Default layout for the appender
  log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
  log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

Step 2: Use it in your Spark application

Inside your pyspark script, you need to initialize the logger to use log4j. The easy thing is, you already have it in your pyspark context!

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) 
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j 
log = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__) 
log.warn("Hello World!")
```